# How to index another disk in Windows?

Tags: windows, search-indexing

I put my Dropbox on disk `D:\`, but this disk doesn't appear in the indexing options.

Is it possible to index another drive in Windows 11?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Should work - works here on a Windows 11 Pro machine with 2 drives and both drives show up in Indexed Locations.  Make sure the Search service is running (default).   Make sure D: is permanently connected and not removable.  Then run DISM / SFC and restart / test.  ... (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.  ....

Comment: Click "show all locations".

Comment: @Moab already tried, it doesn't change anything

Comment: @John How can I make sure the SSD is not"removable"?

Comment: In Control Panel> indexing options (with nothing selected) select "Modify" The drive should show in there.

Comment: If the SSD is fixed in, that satisfies the requirements.  Run DISM as suggested.  Both my drives are SSD.

Comment: @nowox If you right-click on drive D: in Explorer and choose "Properties", does it show a checkbox for "Allow files on this disk to to have contents indexed in addition to file properties"?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Well, this checkbox was already checked :(

Comment: @nowox There is a troubleshooter for indexing: press the Windows key; type "troubleshoot"; select "troubleshoot other settings"; find the entry for "Search and Indexing" and click "Run". Pick an appropriate item, or work through them in order, to see if Windows can fix itself.